# Can't send e-mails from Outlook 2016

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2016, email-client

When I try to send e-mails from Outlook 2016, I get the following error message:

> The operation failed. The messaging interfaces have returned an unknown error. If the problem persists, restart Outlook.

I have restarted Outlook and even rebooted my computer, but the problem still persists. I can receive and read e-mails, but the problem, which just started happening recently, is in sending them.

Does anyone have any idea how to fix this so I can send e-mails again?

Comment: Check the Account Setup in your Outlook Profile. It is possible the ISP changed outbound settings and you may need to do that too.

Comment: That can't be it. I have my personal e-mail account and my wife's work e-mail account on there, and it's doing it for both.

Comment: You may need to be sure your email is backed up and delete the Outlook Profiles and remake them. Take care doing this. I have Outlook for several accounts on both machines and it works well for both send and receive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your description, I noticed that your problem is similar to this known problem: [The operation failed error when you send email messages in Outlook](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/troubleshoot/profiles-and-accounts/operation-failed-send-email-outlook). Please check if your case is consistent with the symptoms mentioned in the article.

If so, it is recommended that you try to configure the two accounts separately in different profiles according to the resolution mentioned in the article.

[image]

Hope to help you!

Comment: Just checking in to see if above information was helpful. If you have any further updates on this issue, please feel free to post back. If you think my reply is helpful to you, please remember to mark it as an answer. Warm thanks.

Comment: That sounds pretty much like my situation. When I get some time, I'll follow the instructions in that article and see if it fixes my situation. Thanks for pointing me to a possible fix.

Comment: Have you tried the resolution mentioned in the article? If it does work, please remember to mark this reply as an answer so that people with similar questions can get reference.

Comment: I'll probably try sometime on the weekend. And if it works, you'll get the check mark.

Comment: Several days have passed. Is the solution in the above mentioned article helpful to you?

Comment: Sorry, but I didn't have any time to try the solution until now. Moving one of the accounts out into a different profile resolved my problem, so you get your check mark.

Comment: Glad your problem has been solved!